# SBS2011 'Exchange Tasks' Missing

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2010, windows-sbs-2011

I've just installed a clean copy of SBS2011 with Exchange 2010 bundled.
I cannot work out how to 'Mail Enable' a contact.

I've read guides and help documents that suggest going into Active Directory, right clicking and choosing 'Exchange Tasks...' but I have no such option.

I don't have any property pages for exchange either. i.e. no 'Exchange General' Tab.

Any ideas what is happening and how I can enable those property pages and functionality?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

For all Exchange related tasks you need to use the Exchange Management Console. Microsoft removed the Exchange related tabs and tasks from ADUC in Exchange Server 2007 and that carries forward with Exchange Server 2010.